# Sorting listview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sorting, listview

I made a listview of players rank and sort it.(by players points)
I leave the first column empty so i can rank the player after Ill sort.
But when I add the players position it add it by the list before the sort

```
Sub sortLv1()
        Lv1.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending
        Lv1.ListViewItemSorter = New ListViewItemComparer2(2, Lv1.Sorting)
        Lv1.Sort()
End Sub
```

Now after I sort it I want to add the position and mark the leader in blue

```
Sub paintLeader()

        For i = 0 To Lv1.Items.Count - 1
            Lv1.Items(i).Text = CStr(i + 1)
            If i = 0 Then
                Lv1.Items(0).ForeColor = Color.Blue
            Else
                Lv1.Items(i).ForeColor = Color.Purple
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

And what I get it in the attached picture
[image]

It look like it sort the list after the ranking even I call the sort before

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I tried to sort it while it was in a `visual=False` state.